# Which is the best camera for image processing?

Tags: image-processing

Now, I have two options, a GoPro and an arduino OV7670 camera module, but if any better camera is available for image processing, I have the budget to buy (less than 100$).

Answer (score 0):

For real time data processing go with the Arduino OV7670, because with the GoPro you would need a HDMI to Arduino video input. WiFi Preview on the GoPro has a ~1-3 second lag and its very low resolution.